# Django: Page not found (404), Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Loader/confirm_booking/17 Raised by: Loader.views.booking_approve

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

working on a project where the user approves the post and then click on the button the post should be approved by the user ...however, while clicking its shows an error like this.

this is model of booking

```
class Booking(models.Model):
     order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True,default='1')
     b_price = models.ForeignKey(price, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='b_prices',default='')
     b_post = models.ForeignKey(Loader_post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     related_name='b_posts',default='')
     booked_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default='')
     approved_price = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

this is my views.py

```
def booking_approve(request,pk):
    booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, pk=pk)
    booking.save()
    booking.approve()
    return redirect('Loader:post', pk=pk)
```

this is my HTML of approval and rejection page where user can reject the offer and approve when it click on approve button the post , user, driver all detail should save onto database and it's not working.

```
{% for loader_post in request.user.Loader.all %} {% for price in loader_post.prices.all %}



 <div class="card" style="margin-right: 30%; width: 22%; margin-bottom: 5%; text-align: left;">


     <div class="container">
    <img src="{{loader_post.image_of_load.url }}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%; height: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px; ">
    <h4><b>Post id : {{loader_post.id }}</b></h4>
    <p>Driver offer : <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{price.driver_price }}</p>
    <p>Offer by : {{price.driver_name }}</p>
    <a style="margin-right:20px;" href="{% url 'Loader:booking_remove' pk=price.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-times fa-4x" style="color: red;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="{% url 'Loader:booking_approve' pk=price.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

this is my urls.py

```
 path('confirm_booking/<int:pk>',views.booking_approve, name="booking_approve"),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add your urls.py?

Comment: update done sir.

Comment: `return redirect('Loader:post', pk=pk)` this section in your `booking_approve` view gives error. because as I see, you have not any url with named post. Do you have?

Comment: yes i have this  page ..its the home page

Comment: where is its url definition? in another app?

Comment: it's in the same app ..when user click on to approve it shows a home page that's it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214257/discussion-between-dilmeet-padda-and-kamilyrb).

Answer (score 0):

as the error displays, it seems that your query does not find a match. Can you please change the query to
booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, pk=1) 
or to another query that you know will give a match? 
You can also include a print(pk) in your view, before the query is called. Then check, if a pk is even given and if so, if the given pk exists within your Booking model. 
If the error dissapears by that, the problem most certainly lies within the call of "pk" for the function. 
Can you please also post your urls?

Best regards

Comment: as per ur concerned sir ...print(pk) print 17 ..and I also put  pk=1 ..whereas it load the page which I mention in a redirect but the data is not saving

Comment: and one more thing there is no pk 17 in my booking... I don't know why it shows 17....but when I put pk=pk then It shows not found in the result of print(pk)

Answer (score 0):

at least we know now, that the 404 error comes from the not found pk, which is nice. There are at least two problems: 
1. no changes are saved. 
2. wrong pk is called. 
The first issue is quite easy to solve. The problem here is, that you call the model object and save it, but you do not make any changes. Thus you need to include something like

```
booking.b_price= = request.POST['new_price']
```

By this, your Booking object with pk=pk will change its attribute b_price to the new given value (after booking.save()). Of course, for this you need to post a value named "new_price" from your html like:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'Loader:booking_approve' pk=price.pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" name="new_price" placeholder="New Price" />
   <input class="" type="submit" value="Change price" style="float: right;"/>
</form>
```

For the second issue, please make sure, that pk=price.pk should give the correct pk within your html.